# Can I filter an Azure ServiceBusService using node.js SDK?

Tags: node.js, azure, azureservicebus, azure-sdk

I have millions of messages in a queue and the first ten million or so are irrelevant. Each message has a sequential ActionId so ideally anything `< 10000000` I can just ignore or better yet delete from the queue. What I have so far:

```js
let azure = require("azure");

function processMessage(sb, message) {
    // Deserialize the JSON body into an object representing the ActionRecorded event
    var actionRecorded = JSON.parse(message.body);

    console.log(`processing id: ${actionRecorded.ActionId} from ${actionRecorded.ActionTaken.ActionTakenDate}`);

    if (actionRecorded.ActionId < 10000000) {
        // When done, delete the message from the queue
        console.log(`Deleting message: ${message.brokerProperties.MessageId} with ActionId: ${actionRecorded.ActionId}`);
        sb.deleteMessage(message, function(deleteError, response) {
            if (deleteError) {
                console.log("Error deleting message: " + message.brokerProperties.MessageId);
            }
        });
    }

    // immediately check for another message
    checkForMessages(sb);
}

function checkForMessages(sb) {
    // Checking for messages
    sb.receiveQueueMessage("my-queue-name", { isPeekLock: true }, function(receiveError, message) {
        if (receiveError && receiveError === "No messages to receive") {
            console.log("No messages left in queue");
            return;
        } else if (receiveError) {
            console.log("Receive error: " + receiveError);
        } else {
            processMessage(sb, message);
        }
    });
}

let connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://<myhub>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=KEYNAME;SharedAccessKey=[mykey]"
let serviceBusService = azure.createServiceBusService(connectionString);

checkForMessages(serviceBusService);
```

I've tried looking at the docs for [withFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-nodejs-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions) but it doesn't seem like that applies to queues.

I don't have access to create or modify the underlying queue aside from the operations mentioned above since the queue is provided by a client.

Can I either

- Filter my results that I get from the queue
- speed up the queue processing somehow?

Comment: did you finally find a way around this? I am looking for a solution too where I want to get a specific message from my queue, guess it defeats the purpose of queues but that is what I need.

Comment: @AbhishekTiwari unfortunately, i never found a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

> Filter my results that I get from the queue

As you found, filters as a feature are only applicable to Topics & Subscriptions.

> speed up the queue processing somehow

If you were to use the `@azure/service-bus` package which is the newer, faster library to work with Service Bus, you could receive the messages in ReceiveAndDelete mode until you reach the message with ActionId 9999999, close that receiver and then create a new receiver in PeekLock mode. For more on these receive modes, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-transfers-locks-settlement#settling-receive-operations